# Как можно реализовать авторизацию в декстоп-приложение?

Tags: java, swing, auth, desktop

Имеется некоторое стороннее dekstop приложение, написанное на java (swing) в котором нужно авторизоваться. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно реализовать это программным образом, т.е. не используя всяких кликеров и т.п.
Что для этого нужно использовать?
Предполагаю, что данные (логин-пароль) для авторизации будут браться из текстового файла.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку [fest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.easytesting/fest-swing). Эта библиотека предназначена для UI тестирования `swing` приложений.

В вашем случае, вы можете написать программу с помощью этой библиотеки, в которой вы автоматизируете логику авторизации.

Если приложение запускаеться через `.exe` файл, то вы можете использовать библиотеку [UIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx). Код придется писать на `c#`/`c++`

Comment: К сожалению, этот вариант отпадает, т.к приложение в котором нужно авторизоватся - стороннее, исходников для него у меня нету.

Comment: А джарник сам у вас есть? Или как вы вообще запускаете это приложение?

Comment: Через exe запускаю. Я просто знаю, что приложение написано было на java, так было написано в документации.
Читал про java access bridge, это вроде не то?

Comment: @Владислав обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

А авторизация происходит через web? Может быть отснифать запрос авторизации (получится только, если нет SSL-пиннига). Если отснифать не удается, то можно попробовать разобрать приложение и поискать запрос авторизации. Я так с юлой делал.